# Why does modifying an array of primitives reduce its performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, entity-component-system

I am looking into the performance of object lookup vs array lookup for a particle system.
Each particle just has x, y values. I can either store these in an object, array, or two separate arrays, one for x and one for y.

In order to iterate over all of my particles I have to store all of the objects in a big array anyway, accessing each object and its properties in order to move and draw the particle. I thought it would be faster to instead store the x, y values directly in arrays, but this jsben.ch test seems to show otherwise, but only when my arrays are sorted randomly. https://jsben.ch/ZR0Ff

The values in the arrays are going to change as particles are updated, added, and removed.
What I don't understand is if my arrays for x and y are just full of numbers and the array behind the scenes is a typed array, how does changing the bits at each index change the performance of the array?

Here is my code:

```
// The thinking behind this test is that it would be faster to iterate over
// arrays containing primitive values than objects
// Instead of storing data in objects, it would all be stored in arrays
// The values at the same index would belong to the same "object"
// In this way you might access the same data more efficiently

var objects = []; // object array full of objects with x and y properties
var x_values = []; // array of numbers representing x values
var y_values = []; // array of numbers representing y values
var combined_values = []; // array of x, y values in the same array

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) { // populate arrays
 
  objects[i] = { x:i, y:i }; // each object has x and y
  x_values[i] = i; // this is the array for x
  y_values[i] = i; // this is the array for y
  combined_values[i*2] = i; // this array goes x,y, x,y, x,y... and is twice as long
  combined_values[i*2+1] = i;
  
}

// shuffling arrays gives interesting results
//shuffleArray(objects);
//shuffleArray(x_values);
//shuffleArray(y_values);
//shuffleArray(combined_values);

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}

function testObjects(objects_) { // loop over all objects
 
  var i = objects.length;
  
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1;
    objects_[i].x ++;
    objects_[i].y ++;
  }
  
}

function testCombinedValues(combined_values_) { // loop over combined values array
  
  var i = combined_values_.length;
  var j = i + 1;
  
  while(i > 0) { i -= 2; j -= 2;
    combined_values_[i] ++;
    combined_values_[j] ++;
  }
  
}

function testValues(x_values_, y_values_) { // loop over two separate values arrays
 
  var i = x_values_.length;
  
  while(i > 0) { i -= 1;
    x_values_[i] ++;
    y_values_[i] ++;
  }
  
}
```

Go to the https://jsben.ch/ZR0Ff and try uncommenting the lines that shuffle the array values. I cannot understand why shuffling an array of numbers would have any bearing on its performance against an array of objects. It seems to me like it should always be significantly faster.

Comment: Even more strange, if I set all the values to 1, sorting still makes my values arrays a lot slower. I believe something is happening to the array object itself when I modify its values, which makes it a lot slower. I thought that so long as the values I was putting in the array were of the same behind the scenes, this would not matter.

Comment: it's a matter of memory implementation. Don't think that arrays are just rows of boxes in memory.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds), it has a nice explanation of how arrays are working in V8.

Comment: Even with an array of primitives? And if that is the case, why would the same sort applied to an array of objects not make that array equally slow? I know object lookup is optimized in JS, but if behind the scenes my array of primitives also turns into an array of pointers, I don't see how it would be any different. Of course at that point I'm looking up 1 object instead of 2 pointers to number values.

Comment: Whoooa, awesome blog post @Teemu. I found that calling the same sort function on the array of objects and then on the arrays of values resulted in the performance hit I was seeing. I guess after I used the sort method on the array of objects, using that same method on the arrays of values converted their element type to something more generic, instead of the faster number type I was expecting. That is awesome!

Comment: Does anyone know if array elements are pointers to values stored in contiguous memory or if the values I put in my array are just stored anywhere in memory? It seems to me now that the performance boost is simply due to a more optimized type of array element rather than lookups from contiguous blocks of memory.

Comment: Given, that you can create an object anywhere, and then assign a reference to an array (or to multiple arrays/variables), and that the references to object's properties are stored in kind a lookup table in the lexical environment record, I doubt the actual values are contiguosly stored, at least when they're not primitives.

Comment: @Teemu, that is perfectly understandable and that was my expectation for objects, but I still had high hopes that primitives stored in an array are actually in a contiguous block of memory somewhere. In further testing, the arrays of primitives are blowing arrays of objects out of the water, and a single array performs slightly better than multiple arrays of primitives, so [x, y] > [x], [y] > [{ x, y }] with high volumes. Even at low volumes arrays of primitives outperform arrays of objects, but that might just be due to a more optimized element type and have nothing to do with contiguous mem

Comment: by varying an index on an array, you force a memory position calculation at each iteration. which is also done in an automated way with the forEach() method but in a directly optimized way. And no, arrays are not necessarily put in a single continuous block of memory, especially when it is updated (primitive or not), and the instructions for manipulating them never assume this principle.

Comment: maybe you would have interest to manage your problem by using an ArrayBuffer and/of blob

Comment: I haven't run the test in a while, but I did add an ArrayBuffer test after posting this and found that it did perform better in some situations. My particular issue was due to calling the same sort method on an array of objects and then on an array of numbers. V8 must have de-optimized the array of numbers, making it about as efficient as the array of objects.